# How can I couple MCNP with FLUKA? To attain reactor dynamics and simulate an ADS(Accelerator Driven System) experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I'm new in Particle Physics based Computing. I want to simulate an ADS experiment (Accelerator Driven System) in subcritical fast system. I was advised to simulate the experiment with FLUKA with MCNP being coupled with it.

On the otherhand, I saw CERN now uses Flair more than FLUKA. is FLUKA and Flair same and if someone can mention how I can couple Flair with MCNP that will be helpful!

I don't know how to actually couple both of them with each other. If anyone can help me out or suggest something that would be wonderful?

Comment: Having used both codes (but not for a decade), I suspect this question (v2) is too complex for our Q&A format. But it could be things are easier now than they used to be. You might also look at [scicomp.se].

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Should I take the question down then?

Comment: There is no harm in leaving it here. If you do cross-post, it is polite to indicate this (with a link) at both questions.

Comment: You can also improve the question by narrowing it. You have so far read X, you have so far tried Y, you are specifically stuck on Z. The answer will probably involve using the output of one simulation as the input distribution for the random number generator for the other simulation. But there are *lots* of choices to make, both physics choices and computer-implementation details which are hopefully less clunky now than they were fifteen years ago.